# How to display a category in a grouped MS Access report even when there are no results

Tags: sql, ms-access, report, grouping

I have a report in Microsoft Access based on a query that shows multiple results. These results are grouped by category in the Access report. Sometimes the filter/criteria in the query causes there to be no results for certain categories which causes that category to not show up in the report.

How do I get the category to still display within the report and possibly show 'None Found' or equivalent statement below the category group if applicable? The end result I would like is to show all categories whether there are results or not.

Comment: Use either LEFT JOIN or RIGHT JOIN in your query.

Comment: Oh okay. So using JOIN in my query will allow the categories to show up in the report even without results, but is there anyway to list a custom statement such as "None Found" underneath the category header?

Comment: @Rene  JOINS do not universally solve the problem of missing data in the result set.  Perhaps an additional query with a new LEFT/RIGHT JOIN will be part of the solution, but definitely not an answer of itself.

Comment: @gluc7  I could give an abstract description of what to do and maybe fabricate a bunch of made-up table and column names, but having actual data schema and perhaps even sample data makes creating an example so much easier.  If a picture is worth 1000 words, so is example data.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you need a UNION query.

Let's say your original query for the report is `qryData`

```
SELECT Category, Data1, Data2
FROM tblData
WHERE foo = bar
```

To find all categories that don't exist in the query, you can use this:

```
SELECT c.Category
FROM tblCategory AS c LEFT JOIN qryData AS d ON c.Category = d.Category
WHERE d.Category IS NULL
```

And for the report, you combine this, e.g.

```
SELECT Category, Data1, Data2
FROM qryData

UNION ALL

SELECT c.Category, 'None found' AS Data1, NULL AS Data2
FROM tblCategory AS c LEFT JOIN qryData AS d ON c.Category = d.Category
WHERE d.Category IS NULL

ORDER BY Category, Data1
```